# How hide output of console.log for object

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have strange problem for me, for my little experience.

In linux i have this output in console.log for object:

**code:** `console.log('PGN=======', pgn[z], '\n');`

**console:** `PGN======= ElementHandle {}`

And this what me need, just info that the object exists.

In Windows i have this output in console.log for object (same code):

**console:**

```
 PGN======= ElementHandle {   _disposed: false,   _context:
 ExecutionContext {
     _client: CDPSession {
       eventsMap: [Map],
       emitter: [Object],
       _callbacks: Map(0) {},
       _connection: [Connection]
       _targetType: 'page',..........
         and many other lines }
```

And this what me not need. How this suppress in Windows?

Comment: Are you looking for `!!pgn[z]`? This gives true if the element is defined, false otherwise.

Comment: No, just supress huge info in console output. console.log(pgn[z].constructor.name) is work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go

```
console.log(pgn[z].constructor.name);
```

(works for primitives as well).

Comment: If the object doesn't exist, then this throws ("cannot read property `constructor` of undefined/null"). Maybe I'm not understanding what OP wants.

Comment: We can guard against null/undefined with `pgn[z]?.constructor.name`